# .NET WSDL Generation xs:choice name the Choice Binding Enums

Tags: .net, web-services, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am generating our Java web services WSDL and then importing it into our C# application each time I make a change.  Every time this is done, the `xs:choice` elements are regenerated but often with a different number depending on which one gets generated first.  For example, lets say when I import the WSDL it generates `ItemChoiceType1` and `ItemChoiceType2`.  The next time I import the WSDL (after changes) it will switch `ItemChoiceType1` and `ItemChoiceType2` so I have to recode the places I used those `ItemChoiceType`s. Is there anyway to rename or specify a name for these constructs, or get them to generate the same way each time?

Thanks

Comment: I have same problem very interested in solution

Answer (score 0):

So this object (myObject) has a property (myProperty) which has a type that may change at build time, and whose values are assigned from an Enum.  Use this property setter function:

/// Set property value from Enum
/// 
private static void propertySetter(Type typeNeeded, object targetObject, string propName, string fieldName)
{
        var theDesiredValue = Enum.Parse(typeNeeded, fieldName);

```
    Type t = targetObject.GetType();
    PropertyInfo info = t.GetProperty(propName);
    if ((info == null) || (!info.CanWrite))
        return;
    info.SetValue(targetObject, theDesiredValue, null);
    return;
```

}

// usage
propertySetter(myObject.myProperty.GetType(), myObject, "myProperty", "enumValue");

Comment: Not sure how this is related to my question can you elaborate?

Answer (score -1):

This is the default behavior of WSDL.EXE.  Because the xs:choice elements are unnamed sequences, they are receiving a name generated by WSDL.EXE.

To my knowledge, there is not a workaround on the .NET side which will not be overridden if you re-import the WSDL.

If you have some control over your Java WSDL, you could specify complexTypes to wrap around the sequences and specify a name for each type.  This may generate a more useful WSDL you could experiment with.